# Preallocating SpatialPolygonsDataFrame in R

Tags: r, spatial, r-sp

I am following the perfect example on how to get spatial data from PostGIS into R from [Here](https://www.r-bloggers.com/load-postgis-geometries-in-r-without-rgdal/).
The example works very well but when I try to retrieve larger datasets (>1000rows) things slow down. This is probably to new memory allocation that has to be done every time (just a guess).
Is there a way to set define the size of `spTemp` prior the loop? The full code here for reference:

```
library(RPostgreSQL)
library(rgeos)
library(sp)

# Load data from the PostGIS server
conn = dbConnect(
  dbDriver("PostgreSQL"), dbname=dbname, host=host, port=5432, 
  user=user, password=password
  )

strSQL = "
  SELECT gid, ST_AsText(geom) AS wkt_geometry, attr1, attr2[, ...]
  FROM geo_layer"
dfTemp = dbGetQuery(conn, strSQL)
row.names(dfTemp) = dfTemp$gid

# Create spatial polygons
# To set the PROJ4 string, enter the EPSG SRID and uncomment the 
# following two lines:
# EPSG = make_EPSG()
# p4s = EPSG[which(EPSG$code == SRID), "prj4"]
for (i in seq(nrow(dfTemp))) {
  if (i == 1) {
    spTemp = readWKT(dfTemp$wkt_geometry[i], dfTemp$gid[i])
    # If the PROJ4 string has been set, use the following instead
    # spTemp = readWKT(dfTemp$wkt_geometry[i], dfTemp$gid[i], p4s)
  }
  else {
    spTemp = rbind(
      spTemp, readWKT(dfTemp$wkt_geometry[i], dfTemp$gid[i])
      # If the PROJ4 string has been set, use the following instead
      # spTemp, readWKT(dfTemp$wkt_geometry[i], dfTemp$gid[i], p4s)
    )
  }
}

# Create SpatialPolygonsDataFrame, drop WKT field from attributes
spdfFinal = SpatialPolygonsDataFrame(spTemp, dfTemp[-2])
```

Comment: Not sure if it will help you but have you tried the sf package in R (http://r-sig-geo.2731867.n2.nabble.com/Simple-features-now-on-CRAN-td7590560.html)?  It's new and I've heard that it's faster than SP for PostGIS

Comment: Maybe it's possible to define spTemp as an empty list (`spTemp = list()`) and then assign at each loop as `spTemp [[i]] <- readWKT(dfTemp$wkt_geometry[i], dfTemp$gid[i])` ?. If readWKT(dfTemp$wkt_geometry[i], dfTemp$gid[i]) is a data.frame, you can then convert spTemp to a data.frame outside the loop with `data.table::rbindlist`

Comment: Besides `sf`, which I recommend (being the author) there are two other packages that would help you: rpostgis and postGIStools, on CRAN, you can check.